# Error al pasar por parámetro nombre de esquema JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Me he encontrado con un problema en el repositorio de spring boot al intentar construir una query nativa con el nombre del esquema por parámetro, dejo ejemplo para ponernos en situación:

```
public interface ModeloRepository extends JpaRepository<Modelo, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Modelo> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM :sch.nombre_tabla;", nativeQuery = true)
    Modelo find(@Param("sch") String sch);

}
```

Y este es el error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : sch.nombre_tabla
```

He probado a pasarle directamente el nombre del esquema y tabla:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM :sch;", nativeQuery = true)
    Modelo find(@Param("sch") String sch);
```

Devolviendo el siguiente error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'my_esquema.nombre_tabla' at line 1
```

Puedo decir también que el tema de pasar por parámetro una variable no es un problema, ya que si lo pasas después del WHERE, no hay ningún tipo de problema.

También he probado a poner el esquema en modo constante y no ha da ningún problema, ejemplo:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM my_esquema.nombre_tabla;", nativeQuery = true)
    Modelo find();
```

Gracias por la atención!

Comment: y si le pones  `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM :sch", nativeQuery = true)` que pasa?

Comment: @RuslanLópez Cierto, se me olvido comentarlo. También lo probé y nada, he modificado el post para aclararlo.

Comment: yo sigo viendo que pones el `;` que no es necesario, no sera eso?